# How to adjust RMarkdown for tables outside the margins and overriden labels in graphs

Tags: r, r-markdown

I would like to fix a couple of imperfections into the .pdf doc I'm trying creating with RMarkdown

[image]

As you could see here I have these series of tables that go out of the margin limit of the sheet. While here

[image]

Labels onto the axis are overriden. I do not know whether it is necessary but for tables I've just run into RMardown doc

````
```{r model, echo = FALSE, results = 'asis'}

iwalk(tables_models, ~ cat(knitr::knit_print(.x)))
````

While graphs come from this for cycle

```
for (i in 5:ncol(data)) {
  p <- ggboxplot(data,
                 x = "COND", y = colnames(data[i]),
                 color = "COND", palette = "npg",
                 facet.by = "SES", short.panel.labs = FALSE    
  )
  print(
    p 
    + stat_compare_means(comparisons = my_comparisons, method = 't.test', 
                         label = "p.signif", ref.group = 'NEG-CTR'))
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix these problems?

Comment: This might be better asked as two separate questions. The overlapping labels can be solved by tilting them 90 degrees with theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is put your R chunk inside an html tag with decreased font size.

````
<span style='font-size: 0.8em'>
```{r model, echo = FALSE, results = 'asis'}
iwalk(tables_models, ~ cat(knitr::knit_print(.x)))
```
</span>
````

Another thing I do when I need it, is to scale page size (%) in the print preview dialog box of the web browser in order to fit it. (eg, 70%).

Comment: Thanks. I just need a bit of more details. I do not know where exaclty set the command you've scripted, since actually   ````{r model, echo = FALSE, results = 'asis'}` is exaclty set after a chunk. So I doubt that  `<span style='font-size: 0.8em'>` has to be placed into the white chunk...

Comment: Markdown allows you to mix html with markdown and R code.
You just place the <span> and </span> around the part of your code that will generate the output you want reduced.

Comment: I am sorry but I am bit lost since this code comes to be found between to consequent chuncks. I have no clue on how to place them

Comment: just put them as given by @user2332849. RMarkdown accepts "any" text around code chunks. I even recommend to leave an empty line before and after the chunk ("let your code chunks "breathe"). When you render (knit) the document, the html tags are interpreted as html. So in your case, place them around the 2 code chunks, if you need both to be scaled.

Comment: The only way that is not marked by red lines is to put those instructions into the white chunk space. By the way this seems do not work. What am I doing wrong?